# Insert comma in numeric columns of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe containing many different columns, some containing string while others containing numeric data. I want to add commas as a thousands separator. Right now, I am trying the below:

```
df= df.apply('{:,}'.format)
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: ('unsupported format string passed to Series.__format__', 'occurred at index Name')
```

Of course I can specify all the numeric column names one by one, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can just using `select_dtypes`

```
df.update(df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).applymap('{:,}'.format))
```

Comment: tried this, but I am still getting the same error though on a different column. When I print its type I am getting `<class 'numpy.int64'>`

Comment: @Ank change to applymap